# How many triplets (a, b, p) satisfy $a^3 - 2ba^2 + 16ap^2 + 32p^2b = 0 $ where $p$ is a prime and $a,b$ $\epsilon$ $N$

Tags: number-theory

How many triplets (a, b, p) satifsy $a^3 - 2ba^2 + 16ap^2 + 32p^2b = 0 $ where $p$ is a prime and $a,b$ $\epsilon$ $N$

I tried solving this question using the quadratic formula since this equation is quadratic in $p$. But I wasn't successful in solving this question.

Answer (score 2):

From your eq we have $$a^2(2b-a)=16p^2(2b+a).$$
If $p\nmid a$ then $p^2\mid 2b-a$.

Write $2b-a=kp^2$.  So $2b+a=kp^2+2a$.  That is
$ka^2=16(kp^2+2a)$ or
$$ka^2-32a-16kp^2=0.$$
The discriminant has to be square so
$$32^2+4\cdot 16k^2p^2=n^2.$$
We must have $n=8m$ and so
$$m^2=4^2+k^2p^2.$$
The only possible value of $kp$ is $3$ so $k=1$ and $p=3$.  Then
$$a^2-32a-16\cdot 9=0$$
or $a=36$ (since $a\in \Bbb N$).  But $2b-a=kp^2=9$ we get $2b=45$ but this is impossible.

Therefore $p \mid a$.  That is $a=px$.  We get
$$x^2(2b-px)=16(2b+px).$$
Then
$$2b(x^2-16)=px(x^2+16).$$

If $p\mid 2b$, then write $2b=py$ so that
$$y(x^2-16)=x(x^2+16)=x(x^2-16)+32x.$$  That is $x^2-16\mid 32 x$.  That is $x-4\mid x^2-16 \mid 32x$.  So $x-4\mid 32\cdot 4=128$.  Therefore $x-4=2^i$ for some $i=0,1,..,7$.  But $x+4\mid x^2-16\mid 32 x$ too, so $x+4=2^j$ for some $j=0,1,...,7$.  That is $2^j-2^i=8$ so $i=3$ and $j=4$, so $x=12$.  Therefore $a=px=24$ and
$$y=\frac{12(12^2+16)}{12^2-16}=15.$$
That is $2b=15p$ so $p=2$. Then we have an answer $(a,b,p)=(24,15,2)$.

If $p\nmid 2b$, then $p$ is odd.  But $2b(x^2-16)=px(x^2+16)$, so $x$ is even.  Write $x=2z$.  We have
$$b(z^2-4)=pz(z^2+4).$$
If $z$ is odd, then $\gcd(z,z^2-4)=1$ and so $z\mid b$.  Write $b=zu$.  We get
$$u(z^2-4)=p(z^2+4).$$
Since $p\nmid 2b$ and $b=zu$, we conclude that $p$ is a factor of $z^2-4=(z-2)(z+2)$.  Therefore after dividing by $p$, either $z-2$ or $z+2$ divides $z^2+4$.  Thus, $z\pm 2\mid 2^2+4=8$.  But $z$ is odd, so $z\pm 2=1$.  Hence, $z=3$ is the only possible value.  Then
$u(3^2-4)=p(3^2+4)$ so $5u=13p$.  That is, $p=5$ and $u=13$.  Hence $b=zu=39$.  Also $x=2z=6$ and $a=px=30$.  We have one more answer $(a,b,p)=(30,39,5)$.

If $z$ is even, then $z=2v$.  So $$b(v^2-1)=2pv(v^2+1).$$  Because $\gcd(v,v^2-1)=1$, we get $v\mid b$.  Write $b=vw$.  So
$$w(v^2-1)=2p(v^2+1).$$
Thus $2(v^2+1)\mid w(v^2-1)$.  Note that $\gcd(v^2+1,v^2-1)=1,2$ depending on whether $v$ is even or odd.

If $v$ is even, then $2(v^2+1)\mid w$.  So
$$p=\frac{w}{2(v^2+1)}(v-1)(v+1).$$
But $p$ is prime, we get $\frac{w}{2(v^2+1)}=1$ and $v-1=1$.  So $v=2$, $w=10$, $b=vw=20$, $z=2v=4$, $x=2z=8$, $p=v+1=3$, and $a=px=24$.  We get another solution $(a,b,p)=(24,20,3)$.

If $v$ is odd, then $8\mid v^2-1$ but $8\nmid 2p(v^2+1)$ because $p$ is odd and $v^2+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

Therefore, all $(a,b,p)$ are $(24,15,2)$, $(30,39,5)$, $(24,20,3)$.  This problem is so long.

Comment: maybe Dietrich Burde's answer has been deleted. So can you also elaborate $p \mid a $ case?

Comment: Dietrich Burde's answer contained an error so it was deleted.  If $p\nmid a$, then $\gcd(p,a)=1$.  So $\gcd(p,a^2)=1$.  But $p\mid a^2(2b-a)$, we must have $p\mid 2a-b$ due to $\gcd(p,a^2)=1$.

Comment: I have 2 doubts. 

1) In the second last line, how did you get " if $v$ is odd then $8 \mid v^2 - 1$" 
2) In 4th line from last, why did you write "$\frac{w}{2(v^2+1)}=1$ and $v-1=1$ "

Comment: @math_freak If $v$ is odd, then $v^2-1=(v-1)(v+1)$ is a product of two consecutive even integers.  One is divisible by $2$ and the other by $4$.

Comment: @math_freak  Be cause $\frac{w}{2(v^2+1)}$, $v-1$, and $v+1$ are integers $>0$.  Their product is a prime $p$, but $v+1>1$.  So $\frac{w}{2(v^2+1)}$ and $v-1$ are $1$, while $v+1=p$.

Comment: is there any proof or reasoning that $kp=3$ in the expression $m^2 = 4^2 + k^2p^2$

Comment: Sure, $(m-kp)(m+kp)=4^2=16$.  But $m-kp$ and $m+kp$ must be both even or both odd (b/c $m+kp=(m-kp)+2kp$.  And $m-kp<m+kp$ so $m-kp=2$ and $m+kp=8$.

Comment: $x - 4 \mid 32 \cdot 4 =128 $ , from where did $4$ come here in place of $x$?

Comment: If $x,a$ are integers and $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients then: $$x-a \mid P(x) \iff x-a \mid P(a).$$  If you want to prove this, first prove that $x-a \mid P(x)-P(a)$ always.